# Adjoint method for imaging with an "analytical" forward model

Tags: optimization, conjugate-gradient

I am working on tomographic image reconstruction (radar regime) of the dielectric properties of objects. As part of my work, I have programmed a ray tracer. This ray tracer is, in a way, purely "analytical" in that rays are propagated from their current location to the next intersection with a surface of an object or the receiver (if applicable), always obeying Snell's law when changing the medium and otherwise travelling in straight lines. In other words: this ray tracer does not use a FEM or anything of the sorts; both signal attenuation and optical path length are simply "accumulated" for each individual ray. Importantly, the ray tracer can follow multiple signal propagation paths. All rays that hit the receiver are summed up.

I want to use this ray tracer as a forward model for image reconstruction, and I want to use the full signal for both the simulated and measured data. My first idea was to use the conjugate gradient method. It seemed very practical because you want to minimize a penalty term, e.g.:
\begin{align}
f = \sum_x (s_{\text{sim}}(x) - s_{\text{meas}}(x))^2 \text{,}
\end{align}
where $s_{\text{sim}}(x)$ is the simulated (complex) signal at position $x$ and $s_{\text{meas}}(x)$ the corresponding measured signal. (Note that these signals consist of a frequency chirp, i.e. the signal at each position is a vector.) Minimizing the penalty term should mean that the objects in the ray tracer have become very close to the true objects in terms of their dielectric properties. (We also assume that the position and size of the objects we put into the ray tracer are already correctly determined.)

However, I realized that this method necessitates the computation of the gradient of $f$ and therefore of the simulated signal with regards to the parameters $p$, i.e. $\nabla_p s_{\text{sim}}(x)$. Here, the parameters are $\mu$ and $n$, i.e. the attenuation coefficient and refractive index of the material. This quickly gets very computationally expensive even with a ray tracer as soon as a few objects are used, since for each object and each parameter the gradient needs to be calculated individually (and then also all possible combinations).

I found out that the adjoint method can solve this problem; it can indirectly determine the gradient with regards to the parameters by instead taking the gradient with regards to the simulated signal. I have also read that you need to solve the adjoint equation, and you basically "backpropagate" the residual signal (i.e. the difference between simulated and measured signal). However, most of the applications I found focus on a forward model which uses a FEM. Since that is not the case here, I have been struggling with finding out how to proceed.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I can implement the adjoint method here, or maybe can point me towards literature that might be helpful in my case?

Comment: I'm much more familiar with the adjoint method as it's used for models discretized with FEM, so this could be way off. But you might find some of the literature on [differentiable rendering](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12057) to be worth a look if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: @DanielShapero thanks, I will check it out!

Comment: Just a thought: Since I'm familiar with elasticity, the adjoint method for static problems in elasticity requires a forward and dual solve pde solve. I solved the forward and dual pde problems using FEM; would it be simply possible to solve these forward and dual pdes using raytracing? What I'm trying to say is, in your case, derive the continuous forward and dual (adjoint) problem and then solve those pdes using ray-tracing.

Comment: If you did things the way I suggested, I wonder how the final expression for the gradient would look like. In finite elements, it involves the shape function associated with the parameter

Comment: @NNN thanks for your reply (and sorry for my late reply, Christmas and all that stuff). I'll look into it; I know that other ray tracers solve the Eikonal equation, I wonder if that is a good place to start. If (or when) I find an expression for the equation and its gradient, I will post here again.